# Appending textbox values to Array list

Tags: java, eclipse

In my java eclipse program i need to fill a array list of string with staff names. So in the GUI I have text-box for the user to enter the name and can press enter so the value goes to the array list.

But now I have a doubt. If I close the program and again run will the new staff names gets appended to the same old array list or will it be a new one.

Comment: Are you seriously asking a question you could answer just by running your program?

Comment: And hint: don't just write up another question now. Using files with java is documented a zillion times here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't do anything to save it and reload it (to a file, database, or elsewhere), it will be a new one.

Comment: That is a separate question.

Comment: Not exactly the greatest answer, but as give so many helpful comments very often you got my vote.